# I'm trying to create a smart contract that alerts the user when the contract expires

Tags: solidity, events

This is what I have tried so far:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract expire {

    uint deployedOn;
    uint duration;

    // deployedOn represents the time at which the contract was deployed
    // deployedOn + duration represents the time when contract should expire
    // this duration has been hardcoded for the purpose of this demonstration
    constructor(){
        deployedOn = block.timestamp;
        duration = 1 minutes;
    }

    // event that is emitted when the contract expires
    event expired();

    // check expiry function checks if the expiry time has passed
    // if yes, then it emits event expired
    function checkExpiry()public {
        if(block.timestamp > deployedOn+duration){
            emit expired();
        }
    }  

}
```

I can't figure out how I would know if the event was emitted or not when I call the checkExpiry function.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the contract expires? Contracts can't do things by themselves, but you can probably get the same effect, by making *whatever cares whether the contract expired* do the checking. E.g. if you want a notification on a website, you can implement this into the website, not the contract.

Answer (score 1):

On the EVM nothing is automatic. A change of state will always happen because a transaction was sent from an EOA (Externally Owned Account).

Hence you cannot do such things from the contract,but there are several tools offchain tools that allow you to send TX automatically to contracts. Such as OpenZeppelin Defender ...

Answer (score 0):

Events are only logged within a transaction that has been recorded in the blockchain; so nope; the event was not emitted

SourcE: [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/solidity/solidity_events.htm#:%7E:text=An%20event%20is%20emitted%2C%20it,have%20created%20and%20emitted%20them.)

Answer (score 0):

Just update your code with this one :-

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract expire {

    uint deployedOn;
    uint duration;

    // deployedOn represents the time at which the contract was deployed
    // deployedOn + duration represents the time when contract should expire
    // this duration has been hardcoded for the purpose of this demonstration
    constructor(){
        deployedOn = block.timestamp;
        duration = 1 minutes;
    }

    // event that is emitted when the contract expires
    event expired();
   //event that is emitted if contract not expired
    event notExpired();


    // check expiry function checks if the expiry time has passed
    function checkExpiry()public {
        if(block.timestamp < deployedOn+duration){
            emit notExpired();
        }
        else emit expired();
    }  
}
```